# Main functions failure (USB Storage, WIFI, SIM, Camera) after boot in Samsung Galaxy Mini 2 running Android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

**PROBLEM**

So far, I noticed that after I turn it on and it completely loads up, it can't:

- show notification-bar
- use camera
- detect or recognize "internal USB storage"
- detect or recognize "SD card"
- use WIFI (when clicked, just says "Error")
- sometimes use cellular network (have good signal strength but can't reach the network)
- sometimes detect "SIM card" (PIN asked on booting but on settings page can't detect!)

---

**WHAT HAPPENED**

My device is pretty heavy on apps (about 200 apps installed), sometimes while I`m working, it hangs and everything just freezes but after about half hour cellular network automatically forced to turned off and everything will be just normal and after reset, net will be back too but the last time that this happened, it took about two hours and when I reset the device, my problems began.

---

**WHY**

I think  all of this is happening because of two reasons:

- the Operating System kernel drivers maybe damaged
- hardware failure (maybe some IC controller fried!)
- because device can't detect internal/external storage so many apps (such as operating system's own apps) can't work properly

---

**DEVICE INFO**

- Model number - Samsung Galaxy Mini 2 (GT-S6500D)
- Android version - 2.3.6
- Baseband version - S6500DJPLI1
- Kernel version - 2.6.38.6-1206137
- Build number - Gingerbread.JPLJ1
- Status - Rooted

---

**P.S.**

I know that I simply can use Android's Recovery mode or Odin for flashing a new Operating System but I don`t want to wipe all of my data (very important to me!)

Comment: I just want to add that **this is not a forum** (consider a [tour]) which means all that flashy formatting is unnecessary here. :)

Answer (score 0):

200 apps on Gingerbread :O, time to upgrade now. Even on my OnePlus One with 3gigs RAM and 64gigs Internal Storage, I merely have 20-30 downloaded apps with 2-3 in start-up.

But anyhow, follow this:

1. Format and install some custom ROM like Cyanogenmod
2. Keep only required apps.
3. Remove apps from start-up. Use [AIO Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.toolbox.full) from Play Store.
4. Use AIO Toolbox on regular basis to clean up.

For all your apps backup: I believe in that list of 200 apps, you must have some system tools. Check if it has backup option for apps or not. Even you can create backup from recovery mode too, if your recovery supports. TWRP/Cyanogenmod/ClockWorkMod do have this option.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i mentioned that i don`t want wipe my all data (in p.s. section!) and about create backup in recovery mode, i agree that`s the best shot if any other ways are dead-end.

Comment: you could backup the whole system via adb, edit the backup, and sideload it back on, keeping all your data. I'll put a more descriptive how-to below.

Comment: I think you're using CyanogenOS that comes with OPO but there is no ROM named "Cyanogen". It's either CyanogenOS or Cyanogenmod and the former is actually proprietary version of the latter.

Comment: @DanB ADB [can't backup the whole system](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/115021/96277).

Comment: @firelord i don`t use CyanogenOS, i just rooted my device and used it normally...

Comment: @DanB i love to try but i cant find such app you mentioned and i`m still searching, but if ADB works instead what firelord said, so i like to try that, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @yek-nafar Umm, I actually didn't use @ for you, neither mention anything related to you. So my comment was meant for the poster of the answer here.

Comment: @Firelord Are you sure? it seems to work doing that for me.

Comment: @DanB Yes I am. Hold on! My claim  is limited to `adb backup`. If you're using that in combination with `adb pull` then of course, the whole system would be backed up (given that the device is rooted).

Comment: sorry for asking but adb is the best? or ClockWorkMod or Titanium-Backup?

Comment: @Firelord I am using them in combination.

Answer (score 0):

as you quoted:

> I don't want to wipe all of my data(very important to me!)

So, A way to do this would be backup editing. You will need the following:

- A PC
- Your phone, rooted, with cable
- adb installed (intall from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio))
- a copy of the stock ROM from online(you made need a MD5 dismantle method, look at this link [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2138885)

Assuming you are not rooted, do this first:
download kingo root from [here](http://d.kingoapp.com/website/KingoRoot.apk) and install it on your phablet. Then, press root and wait. Once it's done, continue on below.

If you do not want to root (even though half this process will unroot it) look at the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)

First, turn on your phone. head to developer options, and enable USB debugging. Then,
 plug you phone, and use the command 'adb root' to ensure no problems, or very few anyway. `adb pull / backup.zip (leave a space between the source i.e. the /, and the place you will save it)` Be sure to to put what you want to save it as.(I suggest backup.zip)
next, with the stock ROM, take it apart (see link i gave you on how) and "loot" the /system file.
Then, open the backup you made, and replace the backups /system with the stock /system. re-zip the modified backup, and boot your device into recovery.
from recovery(must be custom, 2.3 does not have what we need by default) choose an option along the lines of `install update via sideload`,then run this command on your PC: `adb sideload <filename of update.zip>` or, in this case:

```
adb sideload backup.zip
```

And wait. By the time it reboots, it should be in fine condition, without the loss of your data. Good luck :)

Comment: if this works then i don`t know how can i repay you, you saved me, but that``s you said is too advanced, it take time to learn and do it, i hope you guys will be here when i have more issues with this solution, thanks again.

Comment: Dan, I'm not sure if that's a recommendable approach. First, yek will see a lot of `permission denied` errors (as `adb pull` cannot access the entire file system unless the ADB daemon is running in root mode – which is just the case with development ROMs). Second, if the device cannot detect the storage anymore, such a backup would be incomplete at best. Third, flashing such an inconsistent backup to the fixed device might just get it broken again.

Comment: I know. Sometimes, high-risk is the only method. However, in light of this, I'll update the method, and I just had an idea