# How to restore SMS from adb backup file without root

Tags: adb, sms, backup, restore

Similar question to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114437/backup-restore-sms-mms-via-adb-on-a-non-rooted-device):

- I have an `ANDROID BACKUP` file containing SMS history, produced from phone A using `adb`. That phone is gone, and this file is the only record I have of that history.
- I have another phone B, to which I would like to restore that SMS data, *without rooting the phone*.

I know that an `adb restore` of SMS data is not possible without root, and I'd be perfectly happy to have an app-based solution. Unfortunately, all of the SMS backup/restore apps I've found so far use their own file format. Is there one that will restore from `adb`-created `ANDROID BACKUP` / `.ab` files?

Comment: *I know that an `adb restore` is not possible without root* – who told you that? It was introduced exactly for that, being able to backup/restore without rooting. Apart from that: AFAIR *Titanium Backup* can restore from Nandroid and ADB backups (but it requires root). If root is an option, give it a try, and please let us know the outcome. Good luck!

Comment: SMS messages can be backed up via `adb`, but restores are a no-op: the text message app explicitly doesn't participate in restore operations. Believe me, I tried: the restore "completes", but the SMS history is not affected on the device. See the top answer [in the question I linked to above](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114437/backup-restore-sms-mms-via-adb-on-a-non-rooted-device) for some further explanation.

Comment: OK, in that case the phrasing is misleading (should rather be "`adb restore` of SMS messages is not possible even with root", and contain your explanation). Could you please [edit] that? As for the issue: I'm afraid there won't be a non-root solution to this then. All you could do is extracting the messages from the backup – but IIRC, they are not even backed up with ADB. Oh yes, see the linked question for that, it was mine :) So what's not in the backup obviously cannot be restored from it, right?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? I've explained on the linked question why it is impossible to restore. Should I explain the reason in bit different terms? I would need the Android version here, both of the old phone and the new one?

Comment: No, I'm clear as to why `adb restore` won't work. However, it would be totally reasonable for an app like SMS Backup + Restore (or any other that is designated as the primary messaging app) to use the appropriate API to import SMS history from a provided `.ab` backup file…it's totally analogous of how it restores SMS history from its own XML format. Unfortunately, no such app seems to be able to consume `.ab` files.

Comment: My last resort will be to generate an SMS Backup + Restore-style XML file from the sqlite database within the `.ab` backup file I have. A pain I was hoping to avoid, but it'll work.

Comment: Please do post an answer should you end up with success.