# Extract SMS messages from adb backup on the host?

Tags: adb, backup

I have made a backup using the following command:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

Does there exist any straightforward way of extracting the SMS messages from the backup file on the host system? By extracting I simply mean be able to view them on the host system, without involving the Android device at all. No adb restore, no Titanium backup or other Android specific solutions. I.e. are there any tools or one-liner methods available to extract this data in GNU/Linux in particular?

Comment: I don't think your backup contains SMS. See http://android.stackexchange.com/q/114437/96277