# Restore SMS messages from a rooted phone with a broken screen to an unrooted phone

Tags: adb, sms, backup, restore, broken-screen

I'm trying to restore my SMS text messages from my *rooted* Nexus 5 with a broken screen (no display or touch capabilities) to my functioning but *unrooted* Nexus 5X.

I can turn the rooted phone to recovery mode and run any adb command (I managed to pull the mmssms.db file using adb), however, I naturally can't run `adb push mmssms.db /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` to my unrooted phone.

Is there any way to restore the text messages some other way?

Again, I have full root access using adb to my rooted phone.

Comment: Related: [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575)

Comment: Instead of phone B you can use virtual rooted phone. See: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141501/how-to-import-an-existing-mmssms-db-to-an-android-virtual-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to restore my text messages using a borrowed 3rd phone that is rooted!

Using:

- The rooted phone with the broken screen that you want to restore *from* (Phone A)
- The rooted phone with the intact screen that you *borrowed* (Phone B)
- The unrooted phone that you want to restore *to* (Phone C)

Do as follows:

1. On *Phone A*:

   - Activate recovery mode and pull the mmssms.db file using adb: `adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db mmssms-phone-A.db`
2. On *Phone B*:

   - Activate recovery mode and do the same: `adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db mmssms-phone-B.db` (use this later to restore the borrowed phone's text messages. Note the different file name)
   - While still in recovery mode, push the file you pulled from *Phone A* to the *Phone B*: `adb push mmssms-phone-A.db /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`
   - Change the file owner and permission of the mmssms.db file: `adb shell` then `chown radio:radio /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` and `chmod 0660 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`
   - Restart to regular mode
   - Install any SMS backup app (I used [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) but any app would do)
   - Run the app to backup the text messages
   - Copy the backup file to some cloud service that you trust or to your desktop/laptop
3. On *Phone C*

   - Copy the backup file from the cloud service or desktop/laptop
   - Install the same SMS backups app and use its restore function

Don't forget to restore the original mmssms.db to the 3rd party phone!

4. On *Phone B*

   - Restart the phone to recovery mode
   - Push the mmssms.db file you pulled from *Phone B* back to it: `adb push mmssms-phone-B.db /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`
   - Change the file owner and permission of the mmssms.db file: `adb shell` then `chown radio:radio /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` and `chmod 0660 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`
5. Enjoy your restored text messages and return *Phone B* to the friend you borrowed it from ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, as you need root to access the /data folder (for unrooted Nexus 5X).

This question is similar: [Can adb be used to recover SMS messages while in permanent “Safe Mode”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37492/can-adb-be-used-to-recover-sms-messages-while-in-permanent-safe-mode)

Comment: Who said anything about directly accessing the /data folder? It is a bold claim stating that "*This is not possible*".

Comment: @Firelord Well, the SMS DB is in the /data folder. If he were to access / modify the files there, he'd need to have root access. Looking at the accepted answer, a rooted phone had to be used in the end.

Comment: The third rooted phone was a mediator because the original rooted phone was busted. The second phone was never rooted. That's the point.