# Copy messages from my old phone

Tags: sms, 2.1-eclair

How can I transfer my SMS and MMS messages from my old phone to my new phone?

My old phone uses Android 2.1 and it seems that you currently need at least Android 2.2 to log in to a Google account. Therefore, I can't use any tools which require a Google account, such as Android Market/Google Play.

Comment: You can download the app mentioned in my answer [here](https://apkpure.com/sms-backup-restore/com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore). When you are replying, click the "Add comment" button to post a comment. You have previously click to post an answer while you should have clicked comments. Please click on the ? button on the top right of your browser, then take the tour to learn how to navigate the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore). Install it on both phones. Backup the messages from the old phone (preferably in xml format). Transfer the file on the new phone, then use the app to restore the messages.

You can also try the method described in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37494/247431).

**Disclaimer:** I am not related to the app's developer(s), just used it a few times.

**Note:** I am not sure if it still supports Android 2.1 or not.